# Nonce function of blockchain in C. Concatenation of unsigned char array in C

Tags: c, blockchain

I try to add a nonce to my blockchain program. But when I test a program performance by trying to repeat the result (I need to be able to do to verify my chain), I do not get an identical result.

First I have a function which transform a `structure` to `unsigned array pointer` :

```
struct  Test{
    unsigned char data[4];
    unsigned char nonce[4];
    unsigned char hash[32];
}*prev,*next; 

unsigned char *toStringTest(struct Test data)
{
    unsigned char *str=malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeof(data));
    memcpy(str,&data,sizeof(data));
    return str;
}
```

Then, I have a program which give me a hash and nonce:

In this function:

1. I concatenated unsigned char pointer from `toStringTest()` with unsigned char arrat `nonce`.
2. I calculated hash of this concatenation.
3. If the hash starts by `0x00` I save hash and nonce into `next` block. If not, I repeat the function.

```
void hash_with_nonce(struct Test* message,struct Test* new_message){
    unsigned char nonce[4]; //number only used once
    unsigned char buffer[32];
    while(1){
        RAND_bytes(nonce, 4); //this function puts 4 cryptographically strong pseudo-random bytes into nonce. 

        unsigned char* str=toStringTest(*message); 

        int len = sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeof(*str)+sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeof(nonce);
        unsigned char* message_with_nonce = malloc(len);  
        memcpy(message_with_nonce,str,sizeof(*str));
        memcpy(message_with_nonce+sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeof(*str),nonce,sizeof(nonce));
        //I concatenated toStringTest(*message) with nonce

        SHA256(message_with_nonce, sizeof(message_with_nonce), buffer); //calculation of hash

        free(message_with_nonce);   
        unsigned char var[1] = {0x00}; //rule for nonce decision, I want what hash start by 0x00
        if((int *)var[0] == (int *)buffer[0]){ 
            memcpy(new_message->hash,buffer, 32); 
            memcpy(new_message->nonce, nonce,sizeof(nonce));
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char hash[32];

    prev=malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
    RAND_bytes(prev->data, 4);
    RAND_bytes(prev->nonce, 4);
    SHA256("",sizeof(""),prev->hash);

    next=malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
    RAND_bytes(next->data, 4);
    //I just have filled this block with random data  

    hash_with_nonce(prev,next);


    unsigned char* str=toStringTest(*prev); 

    int len = sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeof(*str)+sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeof(next->nonce);
    unsigned char* message_with_nonce = malloc(len);  

    memcpy(message_with_nonce,str,sizeof(*str));
    memcpy(message_with_nonce+sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeof(*str),next->nonce,sizeof(next->nonce));
    SHA256(message_with_nonce, sizeof(message_with_nonce), hash);
}
```

prev and next are just 2 blocks which I use to check if function `hash_with_nonce` is working.

A problem is that the `unsigned char hash[32]` of the main is not the identical to `next->hash`. SHA256() and RAND_bytes() are openssl functions.

To check if 2 hashs are same, I have this function:

```
void PrintHex(unsigned char data[], int size) 
{
    unsigned char tmp[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    { 
        sprintf(tmp, "%02x",data[i]); 
        printf("%s", tmp);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Just a tip, `sizeof(unsigned char)` is guaranteed to equal 1 so you can drop that from all your calculations.  It just clutters up the code.

Comment: `sizeof(*str)` That gives you `sizeof(unsigned char)`. It does not give you the size of the `malloc` memory.

Comment: @kaylum how can get a length of *str?

Comment: You can't get it from `str`. You need to keep track of that in a seperate variable. Though in this case you know it is `sizeof(struct Test)`.

Comment: @kaylum  I have changed `sizeof(*str)` by `sizeof(struct Test)` but the difference between `hash` and `new->hash` still remains.

Comment: `(int *)var[0]` is undefined behavior. No, you can't do that. That's not easy way, that' wrong way. Please create an [MCVE]. What is `prev`? What is `next`? `that the unsigned char hash[32] of the main is not the identical to new->hash` - how do you check that? Where is `new->hash`, it's nowhere in the code you presented. I do not understand your code - what is your code trying to do? Can you add comments explaining what is going on? Please fix the `sizeof(*str)`.